# Jackson ObjectMapper ignores JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL

Tags: spring-boot, serialization, jackson, annotations

I have a project in Spring Boot 1.5.2. For some reason, I haven't been able to make the ObjectMapper ignore null fields during serialization. Here's the setup:

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class CustomerInfo{
  private Long customerId;
  private String fullName;
  //some more fields
  //getters and setters
}

@Service
public class ObjectMapperTester{
  @Autowired
  private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

  public void test(){
     CustomerInfo ci = new CustomerInfo;
     ci.setFullName("Foo");
     objectMapper.writeValueAsString(ci);
     //I get JsonMappingException here
  }
}
```

Up until now, I've always used `@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)` annotation with my classes to ignore null fields. That works perfectly well when I return any kind of object in RestController methods, so I don't see any null fields in the response output. But this one resists working. I get an exception when trying to writeValueAsString when the customerId field is null. The ObjectMapper is trying to get customerId value through getter, which in turn does the following:

```
 //In fact compiler transforms the getter to be so, otherwise I just return the customerId.
 return this.customerId.longValue();
```

And that of course throws NullPointerException.

I've tried instructing the mapper manually to ignore null fields during serialization this way:

```
objectMapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL);
```

But that doesn't help either. Any other ideas?

**UPDATE**

I've sort of figured out the problem. In fact, the type of the `customerId` field used to be the primitive `long`. Then I changed it to `Long` without using the IDE refactoring, which left the getter like this:

```
public long getCustomerId(){
  return customerId;
}
```

And the compiler converted it to

```
public long getCustomerId(){
  return customerId.longValue();
}
```

After fixing the getter return type to `Long`, the problem got solved and I indeed don't get the `customerId` field in the output. But the getCustomerId() method is still invoked. That's why I said `sort of`. Why does the mapper need to invoke the getter if it's going to ignore it? I've tried removing the class-wide annotation and added it to the fields. But still, the getter method gets invoked.

Comment: Why are you doing `customerId.longValue();` in getter? This NPE has nothing to do with `JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL`. Rather you should correct getter method

Comment: I don't do that. The compiler coverts it like that. In fact my getter just returns customerId. But anyway, if the ObjectMapper didn't try to serialize null fields that would cause no issue.

Comment: Surprising. Can you add getter to ques? Jackson is throwing exception is it's using getter not field. You can change it by using `@JsonAutoDetect(fieldVisibility = Visibility.ANY, getterVisibility = Visibility.NONE, setterVisibility = Visibility.NONE)`

Comment: which jackson version do you use? maybe you need to change the code to `@JsonSerialize(include=JsonSerialize.Inclusion.NON_NULL) `

Comment: and maybe you also need this in your property file: `spring.jackson.default-property-inclusion=non_null`